# Sorting by count of matching related data Linq, ThenBy doesnt work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I wrote a query that sorts the result based on the amount of matching elements of a given list. This works when using a single OrderBy.

However, since I want to use Pagination, I need to use a ThenBy to make sure the order is always the same.

The current query somehow moves the subquery inside the OrderBy/ThenBy and can't be translated.

How can I re-write this query so that ThenBy would work?

Thanks.

Code:

```
    products
        .Select(product => new ProductDto(product)
        {
            MatchingContainsCount = (from contain in product.Contains
                where allergens.Contains(contain.Allergen.Name)
                select contain.Allergen).Count(),
            MatchingMayContainCount = (from mayContain in product.MayContain
                where allergens.Contains(mayContain.Allergen.Name)
                select mayContain.Allergen).Count()
        })
        .OrderBy(dto => dto.MatchingContainsCount)
        .ThenBy(dto => dto.Id); // Without this line it works
```

The Translation error:
[image: linq error]
[image: part2]

Comment: Where do you assign value from Product DBContext model class to ProductDto.Id property?

Comment: @DhanukaJayasinghe It's assigned within the ProductDto constructor

Comment: Instead assigning Id property inside the constructor, assign the Id property and other properties within the PropertyDto body, similar to MatchingContainsCount  property. EF core doesn't translate complex property assignment within the class constructor or methods to SQL. Only the simple assignments. This should fix your problem :)

Comment: Have you tried Select(…).ToList().OrderBy(…).ThenBy(…)?

Comment: @DhanukaJayasinghe That's it! Thanks! You can reply with an answer so I can confirm.

Comment: @Dion Happy to help. added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead assigning Id property inside the constructor, assign the Id property and other properties within the PropertyDto body, similar to MatchingContainsCount property. EF core doesn't translate complex property assignment within the class constructor or methods to SQL. Only the simple assignments. This should fix the problem.